# Is it possible to add generics to enum values? Example pseudo-code included

Tags: java, generics, enums

Is it possible to add generics to enum values?

Something similar to this pseudo code:

```
    public enum MyEnum<T> {

            VALUE1<String>,
            VALUE2<Boolean>;

            public T get() {
                    return (T) AnotherSystem.get(this); // Where AnotherSystem.get returns an Object
            }

    }
```

Have I just written this incorrectly, or is this not possible at all?

What other options do I have to make get() return a specific generic type (T)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Enums are pretty much strongly typed constants. I guess you could imagine an generic abstract enum parent class you could subclass before usage (not that the language supports it afaik), but I can't think of a good use case.

Comment: I want to use the Enum values as keys, but I want to associate each key with a specific type (String, Boolean, Dog, etc), so I can write something like: Dog dog = MyEnum.VALUE2.get(); instead of: Dog dog = (Dog) MyEnum.VALUE2.get();

Comment: You're probably better of with 'classic' constants for that use case: public final class MyConstants { public final static Dog VALUE1 =...; public final static Cat VALUE2 = ... }

Comment: agree with ptyx. enum is a convenience; if it's inconvenient for a case, don't use enum.

Comment: @corgrath: There's no way of implementing that in a type-safe way with enums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
        public <T> T get() {
                return (T) AnotherSystem.get(this); 
        }
```

If you need to associate a type with an enum, it can be a property

```
public enum MyEnum {

    VALUE1(String.class),
    VALUE2(Boolean.class);

    public final Class<?> type;
    MyEnum(Class<?> type){ this.type = type; }

    public <T> T get() {
        return (T) AnotherSystem.get(this, this.type);
    }

}

class AnotherSystem
{
    static<T> T get(MyEnum e, Class<T> type){ return null; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe anything like this is possible. If you look at [section 8.9 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.9), where enum declarations are specified, there's nothing about generics there:

Compare it with the "normal" class declaration in [section 8.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1), where part of the spec is the type parameters involved.